# Issue with sum in for loop

Tags: c, sum

Hi sorry this one may be a stupid question but I'm just moving my first steps in C and I couldn't find any specific answer, so:

Let's say I have to sum up some integers, why the expression `sum += sum` , in this code returns just only the last number I enter time 2 (lastNumber*2)?

```
unsigned int count = 0, sum = 0;
printf("How many numbers do you want to sum: ");
scanf("%u", &count);

for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
    printf("enter the integer: ");
    scanf("%u", &sum);
    sum += sum;
}

printf("the sum of all the %u numbers is: %u\n", count, sum);
```

PS: This problem is solved if I replace the expression with `sum += x`;
But I can't understand why.

Comment: `sum += sum` == `sum = sum + sum` sure it is `sum * 2`

Comment: How about using one more variable for input purpose?

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: `sum += x` shouldn't compile at all. Now maybe if you were to `scanf("%u", &x)` after properly declaring x, your solution would be... closer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line

```
scanf ("%u", &sum); // Let's say the user enters "7"
```

you override the value of sum on every iteration with a new value entered by the user. Afterwards you add the user variable again with

```
sum = sum + sum;  // equivalent to sum = 7 + 7;
```

You can avoid that by using two variables:

```
int sum = 0;
int userIn = 0;
scanf ("%u", &userIn);  // userIn has now the value of the user input
sum += userin; // Add that value to the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

When you doing scanf(..., &sum) you actually override its value.
So, each iterate you doing nothing.
Generally, it is good practice to dedicate variable to each purpose. Which means- variable contains the sum, and other one gets the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
unsigned int count = 0, sum = 0;
printf("How many numbers do you want to sum: ");
scanf("%u", &count);

for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
    printf("enter the integer: ");
    unsigned int value;
    scanf("%u", &value);
    sum += value;  // or sum = sum + value;
}

printf("the sum of all the %u numbers is: %u\n", count, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `sum += sum;` equivalent to `sum = sum + sum;` and (sum + sum) equivalent to (2 * sum).